# How to output this numbers sequence?

Tags: c, stdio

**Examples:**

```
enter a number:5
output : 5,10,15,20,25,20,15,10,5

**Example 2:**
enter a number :3 output : 3,6,9,6,3
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){

    int a,i ;
    a=5;
    i=1;

    do{
        printf("%d\t",a*i);
        i++;

    }
    while(i<=5);
int b,l;
    b=3;
    l=1;

    do{
        printf("\n%d\t",b*l);
        l++;
    }
    while (l<=3);
}
```

Please help me with my codes so that I can improve myself and the showing the correct result that is supposed to first increase an then to decrease the given number.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Your code has a reference to Fibonacci sequence, but your example shows the given nuber added to itself up to it square value and back.

Comment: @Cubo78 the input is 5 so that the output will be 5,10,15,20,25,20,15,10,5

Comment: the second the input :3 so the output will be 3,6,9,6,3 @Cubo78

Comment: your series is not fibonacci series

Comment: do you get what i'm telling to you ? @Cubo78

Comment: @erdiyılmaz can you edit it so i can see what part i will be improving myself

Comment: Your code has to many mistake for your output.

Comment: Yes. You have to have to add the original number to itself until you reach its square value, and then subtract it to the sum until you come back to the original value. But I can correct your code since it is completely unrelated. I would have to completely rewrite it. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Cubo78 yes rewrite it so i can see what part i will be improving myself thank you in advance

Comment: @Cubo78 One typo and a little (admittedly helpful) indendation is not enough for an eidt proposal in the presence of more, obvious and easily fixable mistakes. Your edit will probably sooner or later be accepted, but for the future please do a more thourough job for an edit which is supposed to give you reputation.

Comment: Hi Laura, thanks for listening to my advice. Your edit is a decent attempt. Now you have managed to output the first part correctly by indirectly increasing the number to output. Now look at the resulting output for the second part. It is wrong because you multiply by an increasing number. What could you do to get the second part to decrease instead?

Comment: @Yunnosch my intention were good. I actually committed a first significant edit, but then I found out that some errors remained. If I knew I to squash my edit in a single one I would have done it.

Comment: @Cubo78 That is OK, I had that problem in a much more catastrophic version (I actually destroyed the readability and logic in my first edit and the noticed that I cannot fix it anymore...). Have fun and good luck on StackOverflow in the future.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes increase to decrease number

Comment: Yes. What do you need to use a decreasing multiplicator (instead of the increasing one) for the second part?

Comment: yes like 5,10,15,20,25,20,15,10,5 @Yunnosch  and second is input 3 and the output is this 3,6,9,6,3

Comment: That sequence is the goal, I know. Which part of that did you already get right and which part is wrong?

Comment: @Yunnosch the decreasing part

Comment: the part its already right is 5,10,15,20,25 and 3,6,9 but i don't know how to decrease it to be like this 20,15,10,5 and 6,3 @Yunnosch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204245/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-laura).

Comment: Laura, you seem to be taking a break. That is a good idea. Please let me know when you are ready to continue.

Answer (score 0):

To print those kinds of sequences you can also use recursion. Your function would look something like this:

```
void printSequence(int x, int incr)
{
    if (x == incr * incr)
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
        return;
    }

    printf("%d ", x);
    printSequence(x + incr, incr);
    printf("%d ", x);
}
```

So you send starting number and increment to the function. In your case they would be the same number, because you want to start, for example, with 5 and increment it by 5 until you hit 5*5. Your base case is when your number `x` becomes eaqual to `x*x` which is in code represented as `x == incr * incr`. If your base case is true, you just print out current value of `x` and return from the function. And if your base case is not true you want to print out the value of `x` and call the same function again with incremented `x`. Then print out the value of `x` again when you recursively start going back from the last function call to the original one.

If your main looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{

    printSequence(5, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

`5 10 15 20 25 20 15 10 5`